# Request for a time period before migrating question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently my question, [Why Greek Septuagint of Genesis 34:3 refer to Dinah as a virgin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39107/why-greek-septuagint-of-genesis-343-refer-to-dinah-as-a-virgin), is migrated to Hermeneutic SE. I want to ask for the moderators to reverse it. I'm willing to change my question in order to be able to have it on Christianity SE and the one at Hermeneutics SE be deleted. In order to prevent similar case like mine can I request for a time period before a moderator moved a question to another SE? I want to propose a time period let say 24 hours so that a questioner can be informed if his question might be better asked on another SE. Thank you for the moderators who have been working well to manage this site.

Comment: I can't flag my own question at Hermeneutics SE because I'm not a member in that site. I'd be very grateful if someone could flag that question and informing the moderator at that site to have that question deleted. I don't want to ask that question at Hermeneutics SE. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Just ask the question again here, but make sure it is indeed different enough and on-topic.

Comment: I can simply edit the old one. Can you flag my question at Hermeneutics I want that one deleted. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do stuff on the Hermeneutics site then take it up with them. Get an account and post on that meta or flag the post. I'm not sure why you are so "hands-off" with the hermeneutics site. Having an account doesn't mean you have to participate.

Comment: I don't want to join another SE for personal reason. Caleb or another moderator might be able to delete that question and migrate it back to Christianity SE. I won't mind reword my question to fit Christianity SE.

Comment: Like I said, joining and participation ... two different things. Basically, you're asking people to do your laundry right now. It's weird and kind of annoying.

Comment: I guess I'll wait until one of the moderators help me out. I apologize for the unpleasantness I don't want to bother anyone with my problem. I just asking the moderators to migrate back my question so that I can reword it properly and have my question at Hermeneutic SE be deleted because I don't want my question migrated there. Again my apology. I don't even want to join for a personal reason.

Comment: Why should the question get deleted on the other site? It's a good question.

Comment: I don't want my question be asked at another SE. If I was informed initially before my question was migrated I can reword the question so that it doesn't need to be moved. You can ask a similar question at Hermeneutic SE and link to my original question at Christianity SE as a credit. I don't want to have my question posted there. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @AdithiaKusno No I don't understand at all. By posting anything here you grant an irrevocable licence. Posts belong to the community.

Comment: @curiousdannii yes I know. But I intend that question to be posted here. I think it's understandable. It'd be better if before migrating a question, the questioner is informed that his question might be better posted at another SE. So that he can have time to change his question if he doesn't want his question to be moved. I'm sure it does no harm to inform first before moving a question to a better SE which might suit that question better. In my case I want my question at Hermeneutic be deleted and migrated back to Christianity SE. I want to edit it which now I can't because it's migrated.

Comment: @AdithiaKusno Not being able to edit it because it's been migrated is a problem. Maybe one of the mods can help. But there's no reason whatsoever to delete it from Hermeneutics

Comment: I don't want my question posted there. You can ask a similar question there and link to my original question for a credit. I hope next time I can be informed before my question is moved. I prefer to reword my question so that it doesn't need to be moved to another SE. It's my question after all. I respect other people question and in return I hope people respect my own question. I won't migrate other people's question unless first I inform the person and receive a feedback. It's a question of courtesy. I ask where I want to ask it. I don't want to ask it at Hermeneutic for personal reason.

Comment: @fredsbend I think it's reasonable for somebody to not want his question to be moved to a different site.  People have all sorts of reasons for not wanting to be associated with some sites, and it can feel a little bit like the other site "stole" your question -- especially when the other site is a small beta that needs the content.  I am absolutely not saying anything about *motives* here; I'm just talking about how it can *feel*.  How would you feel if your sincerely-asked question here were migrated to, say, Skeptics or Politics?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Foolish. I would feel foolish for asking an off-topic question. Which is exactly what I have felt. Feelings really don't have any bearing on what should be done, if anything.

Answer (score 3):

No, actually that's not the way it works.

I "grace period" just doesn't make any sense in this case.

First of all there is not really any ambiguity about where that question belongs. There are some cases where a question is potentially on topic  on more than one site and which site is best might depend on what sort of answer the OP would prefer. Such is not the case with this question. It is utterly and completely outside the scope of C.SE and exactly square dead center for BH.SE. It's a great question for there and belongs there. It's not ever close to being appropriate for C.SE and does not belong here.

Of course you can ask whatever question you like here on C.SE as long as it fits the local site guidelines, but you can't just pull a question out of circulation because you don't like it. At this point it was given a good answer in good faith by somebody on the BH site that is a good match for the question. Deleting it would unfairly deprive them of their work and since it's a good fit all the way around there is no reason to do that.

If you would like to ask a modified version of the question here on C.SE feel free to try that. But I don't see any reason to reverse the migration. It would be off topic here, so there is no point in migrating it back just to promptly close it, and with an answer there really isn't any reason to delete it.

If for whatever reason you don't want your name associated with the post we can take care of that I'm sure. The CC license you grant when you use this site does allow you to remove your name from things. I think the fastest way to make that happen is actually (and counter-intuitively) to follow the migration and create an associated account there. That will properly claim authorship of the post. Then delete your account, which will properly anonymize your content instead of the limbo state it's in now.

In deference to your stated preference against migration I have just closed (rather than migrated) another one of your questions that was clearly asking something that is in-scope for BH.SE and not C.SE. If you don't want your questions migrated please stop asking things that don't belong here! Questions about "What does text X mean?" or "Can X me interpreted such and such a way?" or anything along that vein are not questions for C.SE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm glad that we have good moderators to keep this site in good circulation. I have two questions but I'll ask the first question first. Can you reopen my original question here so that I can edit it to ask a proper question that belong to C.SE?

Comment: @AdithiaKusno Yes and no. I cleared the meta data so it's dissociated from the migration, which means you can edit it now, but I cannot re-open it because it is currently blatantly off topic for C.SE. If you edit to fix that then we can consider actually opening it.